# How can I declare my appController when using Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I just changed to using Typescript and I am getting an error as soon as I start my application.

Here's the way I define my AppController:

```
app.controller('appController', AppController);

class AppController { 
    static $inject = [
        '$scope',
        '$state',
        'authService',
        'stateService',
        'userService'
    ]   
    constructor(
        public $scope: IAppControllerScope,
        ) {

        $scope.app = this;
    }  
}
```

I checked and the file has been loaded.

However I am getting a message saying:

```
Argument 'appController' is not a function, got undefined
```

Am I declaring the controller correctly? Can anyone help suggest how I could debug this problem?

Comment: Does classes in Typescript get hoisted? If not, perhaps trying to declare the class before using it helps?

Comment: @ivarni This is the reason why it's not working :) and that's is also reflected in ES6 JavaScript compilers like babeljs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be working:

```
interface IAppControllerScope extends ng.IScope
{
    app : AppController;
}
class AppController { 
    static $inject = [
        '$scope',
        '$state',
        'authService',
        'stateService',
        'userService'
    ];
    constructor(public $scope: IAppControllerScope
        , public $state: any
        , public authService: any
        , public stateService: any
        , public userService: any
        ) {

            $scope.app = this;
        }  
}

var app = angular.module('myModule');

app.controller('appController', AppController);
```

Comment: @Radmin - Thanks for your suggestion. It now works or at least that error is fixed and I have another problem :-)

Comment: Great to see that;) angular with typescript is the right choice, I'd say ;)

Answer (score 0):

Alaways first declare the classes/modules and then wire it with Angular. So this will work:

```
class AppController { 
    static $inject = [
        '$scope',
        '$state',
        'authService',
        'stateService',
        'userService'
    ]   
    constructor(
        public $scope: IAppControllerScope,
        ) {

        $scope.app = this;
    }  
} 

app.controller('appController', AppController);
```